# DateUtils.parseDate exception

Tags: java, datetime, apache-commons-dateutils

I can't seem to get this to work, it says Unknown pattern character - "T"

Unable to parse the date 2011-07-22T12:01:34.9455820

```
Date theDate = DateUtils.parseDate(notif.dateStr, new String[]{"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.S"});
```

This won't work either(which is what I was doing first, and in this case it just gave a parse exception):

```
Date theDate = DateUtils.parseDate(notif.dateStr);
```

Where is my error?

Comment: why didn't you accept CoolBeans answer? It didn't work for you?

Answer (score 11):

Try `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S` as the format pattern. Example:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String date = "2011-07-22T12:01:34.9455820";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S");
        try {
            Date dt = format.parse(date);
            System.out.println(dt.toString()); //prints Fri Jul 22 14:39:09 CDT 2011
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: did this solve the original posters problem? simply putting quotes around the T character?

Comment: @towpse - yes it should have. The OP didn't accept, but it's a common problem and has this simple resolution.

Comment: so what if a date format I'm trying to work with looks like this MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt? I think the tt is from the dot net world to specify am or pm pattern at the end of a timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you are not providing a pattern that matches the format.

[DateUtils JavaDoc api-3.3.2](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html#parseDate(java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String...))

```
parseDate

public static Date parseDate(String str,
                             String[] parsePatterns)
                      throws ParseException

Parses a string representing a date by trying a variety of different parsers.

The parse will try each parse pattern in turn. A parse is only deemed sucessful
if it parses the whole of the input string. If no parse patterns match, 
a ParseException is thrown.
```